# syntax error when compiling method in .vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-component

I am following a tutorial (https://savvyapps.com/blog/definitive-guide-building-web-app-vuejs-firebase) to build a vue.js app and in one of the sections of the guide it directed me to add a login() function in the  block of the Login.vue file.

```
    login() {
      fb.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.loginForm.email, this.loginForm.password).then(user => {
        this.$store.commit('setCurrentUser', user)
        this.$store.dispatch('fetchUserProfile')
        this.$router.push('/dashboard')
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      }) 
    }
```

However, when it is compiled I get an error:

```
    ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/Login.vue
Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/Users/Rohit/Documents/Javascript/vue_practice/humanity/src/components/Login.vue: Unexpected token, expected ; (33:8)

  31 | const fb = require('../firebaseConfig.js')
  32 | 
> 33 | login() {
     |         ^
  34 |     fb.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.loginForm.email, this.loginForm.password).then(user => {
  35 |         this.$store.commit('setCurrentUser', user)
  36 |         this.$store.dispatch('fetchUserProfile')

 @ ./src/components/Login.vue 4:0-105 5:0-118
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

I have been trying my best to figure out what the syntax error is but to no avail. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`login()` belongs in the `methods` object of the component:

```
export default {
  methods: {
    login() {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `script` section you must have the following structure :

```
<script>
const fb = require('../firebaseConfig.js')
export default{
 data(){
     return { ... };
  },
methods:{
   ...
    login() {
      fb.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.loginForm.email, 
       this.loginForm.password).then(user => {
        this.$store.commit('setCurrentUser', user)
       this.$store.dispatch('fetchUserProfile')
       this.$router.push('/dashboard')
     }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
     }) 
    }
  ...
   }
}
</script>
```